# Issues with CSS and Links

Tags: css, hyperlink, font-face

Looks like you guys were right. Changing the order has fixed the problem. Seems like such an easy fix. Thanks for all the comments/help.

---

I am having some issues with my links and css. Below is my code for the site. My problem is I have 5 links all using the same class. They all display correctly and the links work fine but the hover and active do not change on the first. The last three work just how they should. Why is this? What is going on? I have deleted it all and re-typed it. I have tried different browsers. Deleted the cache. Nothing.

HTML Code:

```
<tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
    <td rowspan="2">
        <img src="images/layout/header-menu/menu_02.gif" width="57" height="51" alt=""></td>
  <td align="center" height="29"><a href="index.php" class="menu">Home</a></td>
    <td rowspan="2">
        <img src="images/layout/header-menu/menu_04.gif" width="41" height="51" alt=""></td>
  <td align="center" height="29"><a href="about.php" class="menu">About</a></td>
    <td rowspan="2">
        <img src="images/layout/header-menu/menu_06.gif" width="36" height="51" alt=""></td>
  <td align="center" height="29"><a href="products.php" class="menu">Products</a></td>
    <td rowspan="2">
        <img src="images/layout/header-menu/menu_08.gif" width="36" height="51" alt=""></td>
  <td align="center" height="29"><a href="recipes.php" class="menu">Recipes</a></td>
    <td rowspan="2">
        <img src="images/layout/header-menu/menu_10.gif" width="36" height="51" alt=""></td>
  <td align="center" height="29"><a href="contact.php" class="menu">Contact</a></td>
    <td rowspan="2">
        <img src="images/layout/header-menu/menu_12.gif" width="58" height="51" alt=""></td>
```

CSS Code:

```
a.menu:link {
color: #94AA45;
text-decoration: none;
font-family: TektonPro-BoldExt-FF, TektonPro-BoldExt, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 22px;
font-weight: normal;}

a.menu:hover {
color: #713010;
text-decoration: none;
font-family: TektonPro-BoldExt-FF, TektonPro-BoldExt, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 22px;
font-weight: normal;}

a.menu:active {
color: #F9A22E;
text-decoration: none;
font-family: TektonPro-BoldExt-FF, TektonPro-BoldExt, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 22px;
font-weight: normal;}

a.menu:visited {
color: #94AA45;
text-decoration: none;
font-family: TektonPro-BoldExt-FF, TektonPro-BoldExt, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 22px;
font-weight: normal;}
```

Comment: Please post your code in a fiddle.

Comment: What happens when you change it to .menu a:hover ?

Comment: @ultraloveninja But the `<a>` is the element with the class `menu`, no?

Comment: This is not a modern way to make a menu. Don't use layout tables. Only for tabular data. Use unordered list. Use background images. Give the ul a class attribute. In hover, visited, and active pseudo class only add the styles that change, not the ones that stay the same.

Answer (score 0):

Set the visited to appear after link in your CSS.

Way I remember is: **L**o**V**e **HA**te

Tested in my browsers and works when re-arranged.  Problem is your visited style is the same as your link style, and overrides the hover (when you are on index.php)

Answer (score 0):

Put your link css in this order:

a

a:visited

a:hover

a:active

For your example, this css should work as expected:

```
    a.menu:link {
    color: #94AA45;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: TektonPro-BoldExt-FF, TektonPro-BoldExt, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: normal;}

    a.menu:visited {
    color: #94AA45;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: TektonPro-BoldExt-FF, TektonPro-BoldExt, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: normal;}


    a.menu:hover {
    color: #713010;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: TektonPro-BoldExt-FF, TektonPro-BoldExt, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: normal;}

    a.menu:active {
    color: #F9A22E;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: TektonPro-BoldExt-FF, TektonPro-BoldExt, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: normal;}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Artur is right and so is @Guido.

You definitely don't want to use tables for navigation elements.

Here's what I did with your code:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="menu">
<td rowspan="2">
    <img src="images/layout/header-menu/menu_02.gif" width="57" height="51"
    alt="">
</td>
<td align="center" height="29"><a href="#" class="menu">Home</a>
</td>
<td rowspan="2">
    <img src="images/layout/header-menu/menu_04.gif" width="41" height="51"
    alt="">
</td>
<td align="center" height="29"><a href="#" class="menu">About</a>
</td>
<td rowspan="2">
    <img src="images/layout/header-menu/menu_06.gif" width="36" height="51"
    alt="">
</td>
<td align="center" height="29"><a href="#" class="menu">Products</a>
</td>
<td rowspan="2">
    <img src="images/layout/header-menu/menu_08.gif" width="36" height="51"
    alt="">
</td>
<td align="center" height="29"><a href="#" class="menu">Recipes</a>
</td>
<td rowspan="2">
    <img src="images/layout/header-menu/menu_10.gif" width="36" height="51"
    alt="">
</td>
<td align="center" height="29"><a href="#" class="menu">Contact</a>
</td>
<td rowspan="2">
    <img src="images/layout/header-menu/menu_12.gif" width="58" height="51"
    alt="">
</td>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
  .menu a {
    color: #94AA45;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: TektonPro-BoldExt-FF, TektonPro-BoldExt, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: normal;
}
.menu a:visited {
    color: #94AA45;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: TektonPro-BoldExt-FF, TektonPro-BoldExt, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: normal;
}
.menu a:hover {
    color: #713010;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: TektonPro-BoldExt-FF, TektonPro-BoldExt, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: normal;
}
.menu a:active {
    color: #F9A22E;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: TektonPro-BoldExt-FF, TektonPro-BoldExt, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

I also made a fiddle for this as well:

http://jsfiddle.net/ultraloveninja/D5rUR/